# Compute marginal effects of slope in mixed model with interactions (between categorical and metric covariates)

Tags: r, lme4, sjplot, marginal-effects

I currently work on a mixed model, that includes multiple interactions of a categorical variable and a metric cost variable to predict a metric output. I'm very interested in the changes of the linear relationship between cost and output (slope) due to the numerous categorical variables.

Because I have multiple categorical covariates that interact with the cost (and there are also random effects) I look for a straightforward method to compute the marginal effects of these slopes. I'm not looking for a prediction or expectation of the output, but would rather like to see the "marginal slope" instead.

I've included some example code below

```r
library(housingData)
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'Matrix'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:tidyr':
#> 
#>     expand, pack, unpack

set.seed(12345)
df <- housing %>%
  filter(complete.cases(.)) %>% 
  mutate(house_type = factor(sample(c("A", "B", "C"), nrow(.), replace = TRUE)),
         timeperiod = as.factor(if_else(lubridate::year(time) < 2012,
                                        "before_2012",
                                        "2012_and_after")))

# model categorical effects on slope, after main effect has been fitted
lm1 <- lm(medSoldPriceSqft ~ 0 + medListPriceSqft, data = df)
coef(lm1)
#> medListPriceSqft 
#>        0.9137324
df2 <- df %>% 
  modelr::add_residuals(lm1, "medSoldPriceSqft_after_list_price")


mod2 <- lmer(medSoldPriceSqft_after_list_price ~ 0 + medListPriceSqft:house_type
  + medListPriceSqft:timeperiod +
  (0 + medListPriceSqft:house_type + medListPriceSqft:timeperiod| state), data = df2)


fixef(mod2)
#>           medListPriceSqft:house_typeA           medListPriceSqft:house_typeB 
#>                             0.02819789                             0.01725657 
#>           medListPriceSqft:house_typeC medListPriceSqft:timeperiodbefore_2012 
#>                             0.01733967                             0.01526881
ranef(mod2)$state
#>    medListPriceSqft:house_typeA medListPriceSqft:house_typeB
#> AL                -0.0332371439                -0.0342472679
#> AR                -0.0161834913                -0.0197485094
#> AZ                -0.0455633279                -0.0540328340
#> CA                -0.0073736100                -0.0069451237
#> CO                -0.0998324113                -0.2144934915
#> CT                -0.0068844784                -0.0064218278
#> DC                 0.1323688987                 0.1625294726
#> DE                 0.0194554114                 0.0240963193
#> FL                -0.0937513315                -0.1128399131
#> GA                -0.0404177163                -0.0447775564
#> IA                -0.0018353661                -0.0065783305
#> ID                 0.0715311714                 0.0827129047
#> IL                 0.0364040836                 0.0519384804
#> IN                 0.3815562061                 0.5127737560
#> KS                 0.3195998033                 0.3735174115
#> KY                 0.0180534996                 0.0284589475
#> LA                -0.0034512710                 0.0002398266
#> MA                 0.0350797588                 0.0495612406
#> MD                -0.0061851180                 0.0030358059
#> ME                -0.1205435796                -0.1434406842
#> MI                -0.0104773953                -0.0097225674
#> MN                 0.0658291099                 0.0815773829
#> MO                 0.1658471055                 0.2092785032
#> MS                 0.0757674725                 0.0957259331
#> MT                -0.2226956530                -0.2848157760
#> NC                -0.0801849629                -0.0930100202
#> ND                 0.1471279546                 0.1632516890
#> NE                -0.0067148446                -0.0091668294
#> NH                -0.0288545182                -0.0318590020
#> NJ                 0.0419945037                 0.0452393238
#> NM                -0.3402646109                -0.4196645043
#> NV                -0.0319233561                -0.0379518075
#> NY                -0.0458677598                -0.0460468454
#> OH                 0.0053817946                 0.0082642996
#> OK                -0.0197739286                -0.0218087721
#> OR                -0.0312838479                -0.0325376041
#> PA                 0.0548995292                 0.0837696293
#> RI                -0.0301300132                -0.0360929264
#> SC                -0.0627597227                -0.0749119310
#> TN                 0.0327156573                 0.0397181302
#> TX                 0.0813191504                 0.0826967005
#> UT                -0.0078590502                -0.0157365323
#> VA                -0.0007437153                 0.0095222182
#> VT                -0.1811751876                -0.2204967507
#> WA                -0.0090309685                -0.0112995414
#> WI                -0.0244199376                -0.0283874222
#> WV                -0.0755127962                -0.0908736075
#>    medListPriceSqft:house_typeC medListPriceSqft:timeperiodbefore_2012
#> AL                -0.0161539511                           -0.033273312
#> AR                -0.0143981558                           -0.002542357
#> AZ                -0.0354905346                           -0.022865789
#> CA                -0.0023188159                           -0.016206762
#> CO                -0.1891388131                           -0.044702463
#> CT                -0.0025396683                           -0.007847727
#> DC                 0.0915280219                            0.147291653
#> DE                 0.0138827021                            0.019724991
#> FL                -0.0701567701                           -0.084079270
#> GA                -0.0260708779                           -0.036974280
#> IA                -0.0102049733                            0.015404515
#> ID                 0.0420144801                            0.079569678
#> IL                 0.0595382970                           -0.072987720
#> IN                 0.4171418424                           -0.035008222
#> KS                 0.1945214096                            0.349026709
#> KY                 0.0298359996                           -0.024003880
#> LA                 0.0102208245                           -0.036621369
#> MA                 0.0494285509                           -0.034373164
#> MD                 0.0074462978                           -0.007041631
#> ME                -0.0886152719                           -0.076925785
#> MI                -0.0009559257                           -0.024871313
#> MN                 0.0334029227                            0.132315832
#> MO                 0.1447632248                            0.074557543
#> MS                 0.0624490008                            0.054095381
#> MT                -0.2229587595                            0.002527347
#> NC                -0.0581766037                           -0.062570993
#> ND                 0.0566945904                            0.254531126
#> NE                -0.0065563090                           -0.003424448
#> NH                -0.0121567614                           -0.046952309
#> NJ                 0.0457664635                           -0.067748718
#> NM                -0.2712390810                           -0.211903077
#> NV                -0.0242007544                           -0.018678370
#> NY                -0.0430582366                            0.108457835
#> OH                 0.0151824401                           -0.038200489
#> OK                -0.0100685546                           -0.023278317
#> OR                -0.0151429366                           -0.036220790
#> PA                 0.0781025694                           -0.026947879
#> RI                -0.0300959629                            0.012527652
#> SC                -0.0372963600                           -0.092552679
#> TN                 0.0308868734                           -0.001932841
#> TX                 0.0381596134                            0.076102496
#> UT                -0.0305654079                            0.070222766
#> VA                 0.0037802116                            0.046899465
#> VT                -0.1400341335                           -0.118380902
#> WA                -0.0022661974                           -0.027577840
#> WI                -0.0106677175                           -0.046255988
#> WV                -0.0542188035                           -0.060304313


# make marginal effects accessible
## Average increase in medListPriceSqft-Slope for house_typeA and timeperiodbefore_2012
fixef(mod2)["medListPriceSqft:house_typeA"] + fixef(mod2)["medListPriceSqft:timeperiodbefore_2012"]
#> medListPriceSqft:house_typeA 
#>                    0.0434667

## Average increase in medListPriceSqft-Slope for house_typeA ()
prop_before_2012 <- table(df2$timeperiod)["before_2012"] / nrow(df2)
fixef(mod2)["medListPriceSqft:house_typeA"] +
  fixef(mod2)["medListPriceSqft:timeperiodbefore_2012"] * prop_before_2012
#> medListPriceSqft:house_typeA 
#>                   0.03564273

## Average increase in medListPriceSqft-Slope for timeperiodbefore_2012
# ...

## Average increase in medListPriceSqft-Slope for house_typeA () for state == "WA"
# ...
```

As you see, this get's tedious quickly, how can I do this programmatically? The packages `{margins}` or `{ggeffects}` seem to cover marginal effects for the output only?

Comment: You may try [`estimate_slope()`](https://easystats.github.io/modelbased/reference/estimate_slopes.html).

Comment: What a useful function! Is there a way to run the computation only on a sample of the original data or a different method to avoid memory problems for bigger data?